# Run multiple AspNetCore WebApi on same port (not in IIS)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

We have a pool of `.Net 4.7.2` WebApis which we host with nuget `Microsoft.Owin.Hosting` (not in `IIS`). All these programs and their web controllers listen on the same port but different virtual paths, e.g. `http://ourserver:4711/ServiceA/` and `http://ourserver:4711/ServiceB/`
The Owin nuget for 4.7.2 seems to create a host in memory when the first service starts and all others just register their virtual paths and everything gets routed just fine.

Reason for using a single port are firewall rules and load balancing etc.

Now we try to migrate to `.Net6`  and while there is a nuget `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin` we can't get it to work. For testing we're using the sample `WheatherForecastController`

Goal 1) We want it to listen on the virtual path `http://localhost:4711/ServiceA/` but not on the root path `http://localhost:4711` at which we fail already.

Goal 2) Start a second, independent exe which then listens on `http://localhost:4711/ServiceB/`

Here's the basic setup for the Owin package that we have so far and we've played with all kinds of settings which don't seem to have any effect for our purposes.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseUrls("http://localhost:4711/")        
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}

public sealed class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddMvc(sa =>
        {
            sa.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UsePathBase("/ServiceA")
           .Use((context, next) =>
           {
               context.Request.PathBase = "/ServiceA";
               return next();
           })
           .UseRouting()
           .UseMvc()
           .UseOwin();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is possible to serve multiple ASP Net Core Web Api on the same port using a reverse proxy. For example: IIS, Nginx...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay, we figured it out, with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65326579/2334520)

We can't use `Kestrel` but since we live in a Windows-only environment, we don't need to. We can revert to the old `HttpSys` for this and then it works. Basic setup:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();

#pragma warning disable CA1416 // Validate platform compatibility
builder.WebHost.UseHttpSys(o => // Windows only
{
    o.UrlPrefixes.Add("http://localhost:4711/ServiceA"); //unique virtual path
});
#pragma warning restore CA1416
```